# Spring Controller with inner class as a parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request, inner-classes

I have a Spring controller with a method mapped to request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/album", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void generateAlbum(GenerateAlbumParams params, HttpServletResponse response){
...
}
```

**GenerateAlbumParams** is a simple class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class GenerateAlbumParams {

    public enum Position {LEFT_TOP, LEFT_BOTTOM, RIGHT_TOP, RIGHT_BOTTOM}
    private List<SlideParams> slideParams = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and **SlideParams** is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SlideParams{
    private Boolean checked = false;
    private Long id;
    private GenerateAlbumParams.Position mapLegendPosition;
    private GenerateAlbumParams.Position mapTablePosition;
}
```

Everything works fine, but if I want make **SlideParams** as inner class of **GenerateAlbumParams**:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class GenerateAlbumParams {

    public enum Position {LEFT_TOP, LEFT_BOTTOM, RIGHT_TOP, RIGHT_BOTTOM}
    private List<SlideParams> slideParams = new ArrayList<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class SlideParams{
        private Boolean checked = false;
        private Long id;
        private Position mapLegendPosition;
        private Position mapTablePosition;
    }
}
```

it thows an exception:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property
>   'slideParams[0]' of bean class
>   [xxx.GenerateAlbumParams]: Illegal
>   attempt to get property 'slideParams' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException:
>   Invalid property 'slideParams' of bean class
>   [xxx.GenerateAlbumParams]: Could not
>   instantiate property type
>   [xxx.GenerateAlbumParams$SlideParams]
>   to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [xxx.GenerateAlbumParams$SlideParams]:
>   Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   xxx.GenerateAlbumParams$SlideParams

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you should make your inner class `static` so it can be instantiated without reference to any objects of outer class (e.g. `new GenerateAlbumParams.SlideParams()`